# Is there any alternate way of converting zlib compressor function for Flutter (Dart)?

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, zlib

I want to compress data using zlib compressor, but this package is not available in Flutter version 3.3.10 and Dart version 2.18.6.

I was trying to convert data in in unit8List and compress it using zlib compressor.

I want data to get compress just like zlib compressor functionality.

Comment: "I want to compress data using zlib compressor but this package is not available in Flutter version 3.3.10" - 3.3.10: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/zlib-constant.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.